# How to populate data cells in Javascript vertically?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this (name, value) table in HTML and I want to populate the 'value' column after some computations.

The 'name' column is filled up at the time of loading of the webpage, while the 'value' column remains blank at that time.

After performing some computations, I'd like to populate the 'value' column for each row corresponding to the 'name', serially. From 1 -> n.

What my page does:

1. Get a number from the user (say 3).
2. Get 3 names.
3. Print out a table of 3 rows of  pairs, leaving the 'value' column blank.
4. Perform some computation and store them in an array called 'value'.

What next:

---

**I want to populate the 'value' column for every element stored in the 'value' array, serially i.e. from 1 -> n.**

---

Here's some code:

**JavaScript - Dynamic creation of the table according to the number received at the beginning**

```
var playerTable = document.getElementById("player_table");
var player_table_row, player_table_datacell1, player_table_datacell2;
var value;

    //no_of_players contains the number of rows
    for ( var i = 0; i < no_of_players; i++)
    {
        //inserts i'th row
        player_table_row = playerTable.insertRow(i);

        //Insert first datacell for the row
        player_table_datacell1 = player_table_row.insertCell( 0 );
        //Insert second datacell for the row
        player_table_datacell2 = player_table_row.insertCell( 1 );

        //Inserts the name for the i'th row in the 'name' column
        //players_list is the array containing all the names
        player_table_datacell1.innerHTML = players_list[i];
        //Leave the second cell i.e. 'value' column blank
        player_table_datacell2.innerHTML = "";


        value[i] = /* Some computations */
    }
```

**HTML code for the table, it's a simple one**

```
<table id = "player_table">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Value</th>
</table>
```

Expected output:

---

```
Name    Value
A       5
B       2
C       19
```

I have calculated those values 5, 2, 19 in advance and now just need to populate them in the HTML table. My current table looks like this:

```
Name    Value
A       
B       
C
```

Comment: Can you post what is your expected output? And what problem are you facing?

Comment: You seem to have an idea of how to fill the table. What is the problem with it? Contrary to what the text says, the HTML code for the table has just two cells, and it is even syntactically malformed. So does the table actually contain the names (how?), or doesn’t it?

Comment: @Yasin I've updated my question according to what I require as an output.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Each row has only 2 cells. The number of rows changes depending on the input supplied to the variable 'no_of_players', that has been taken from the user prompt much earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your computations require some kind of user input. And that is the reason why, you couldn't do the computation and then add rows to the table with Name and computed values.

Here is one way of doing it. I am just setting the id for each value cell and use the id to update. Hope it helps :)

```
<body>
    <table id = "player_table">
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </thead>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        process();

        function process() {
            var playerTable = document.getElementById("player_table");
            var player_table_row, player_table_datacell1, player_table_datacell2;
            var value;

            //hard coding for testing purposes
            no_of_players = 3;
            var players_list = ["A", "B", "C"];

            //no_of_players contains the number of rows
            for (var i = 0; i < no_of_players; i++) {
                //inserts i'th row
                player_table_row = playerTable.insertRow(i + 1);

                //Insert first datacell for the row
                player_table_datacell1 = player_table_row.insertCell(0);
                //Insert second datacell for the row
                player_table_datacell2 = player_table_row.insertCell(1);
                player_table_datacell2.id = "value_cell_" + String(i);

                //Inserts the name for the i'th row in the 'name' column
                //players_list is the array containing all the names
                player_table_datacell1.innerHTML = players_list[i];
                //Leave the second cell i.e. 'value' column blank
                player_table_datacell2.innerHTML = "";

                //value[i] = /* Some computations */
            }
            value = ["100", "200", "300"]; //hard coding for testing purposes
            updateValueColumn(value);
        }

        function updateValueColumn(value) {
            var value_cell;
            for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                value_cell = document.getElementById("value_cell_" + String(i));
                value_cell.innerHTML = value[i];
            }
        }    
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Yeah this worked. I tweaked my code to include the 'id' value for the 'player_table_datacell2' variable dynamically (which I was not aware of). And also, just a clarification that my values are ready with me. I have them calculated. They aren't really linked to the HTML in any way. My only problem was how to display them.

Answer (score 0):

With a generated table like this:

```
<table id = "player_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You could use this code to get the second column as an array:

```
var valueCells = document.querySelectorAll("#player_table tr td:nth-child(2)");
```

Then just set the innerHTML on each cell in some loop.

```
valueCells[i].innerHTML = value[i];
```